# Как корректно описать функцию в typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

TS

```
type Prop = {
  default?: any;
  get?: Function;
  set?: Function;
}

type Model = {
  is: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}

function convertModel(model: Model) {
  const obj = Object.create(null);
  for (const p in model) {
    if (p === 'is') continue;
    const prop = model[p];
    const desc = Object.create(null);
    if (prop.get || prop.set) {
      desc.get = prop.get;
      desc.set = prop.set;
    }
    else if (prop.default !== undefined) {
      desc.value = prop.default ?? prop.value;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(obj, p, desc);
  }
  return obj;
}
function FABRIC(model: Model) {
  const name = model?.is;
  const proto = convertModel(model);
  const cls = class extends (this || Object) {
    constructor(...args) {
      super(...args);
      for (const k in proto) {
        Object.defineProperty(this, k, proto[k]);
      }
    }
  };
  if (name) {
    Object.defineProperty(cls, 'name', { value: name });
    Object.defineProperty(cls.prototype, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: name });
  }
  const fn = function () {
    if (!new.target)
      return FABRIC.call(fn.cls, ...arguments);
    return new fn.cls(...arguments);
  };
  fn.cls = cls;
  Object.defineProperty(fn, Symbol.hasInstance, { value: (obj) => obj instanceof fn.cls });
  Object.defineProperty(fn, 'name', { value: name });
  return fn;
}
// examples
const A = FABRIC({ is: 'A' });
const obj_b = new A();
const C = A({ is: 'C' });
const obj_c = new C();
console.log(obj_c instanceof C); //true
console.log(obj_c instanceof A); //true
```

JS

```
function convertModel(model) {
    const obj = Object.create(null);
    for (const p in model) {
        if (p === 'is')
            continue;
        const prop = model[p];
        const desc = Object.create(null);
        if (prop.get || prop.set) {
            desc.get = prop.get;
            desc.set = prop.set;
        }
        else if (prop.default !== undefined) {
            desc.value = prop.default ?? prop.value;
        }
        Object.defineProperty(obj, p, desc);
    }
    return obj;
}
function FABRIC(model) {
    const name = model?.is;
    const proto = convertModel(model);
    const cls = class extends (this || Object) {
        constructor(...args) {
            super(...args);
            for (const k in proto) {
                Object.defineProperty(this, k, proto[k]);
            }
        }
    };
    if (name) {
        Object.defineProperty(cls, 'name', { value: name });
        Object.defineProperty(cls.prototype, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: name });
    }
    const fn = function () {
        if (!new.target)
            return FABRIC.call(fn.cls, ...arguments);
        return new fn.cls(...arguments);
    };
    fn.cls = cls;
    Object.defineProperty(fn, Symbol.hasInstance, { value: (obj) => obj instanceof fn.cls });
    Object.defineProperty(fn, 'name', { value: name });
    return fn;
}
// examples
const A = FABRIC({ is: 'A' });
const obj_b = new A();
const C = A({ is: 'C' });
const obj_c = new C();
console.log(obj_c instanceof C); //true
console.log(obj_c instanceof A); //true
```

Сейчас `new A()` выводит ошибку: "Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword."

Функция `FABRIC` создает класс, создает функцию, связывает класс с функцией и возвращает функцию. Эта функция может быть вызвана как обычно, тогда она вызовет `FABRIC` и вернет её результат, или через "new" тогда она вернет объекта класса. В JS все работает, но TS ругается. Как описать функцию так, чтобы она работала так же, но код был бы действителен для typescript, при этом не отключая правила (я не хочу терять подсказки)?

Comment: "В JS все работает" - доказать сможешь?

Comment: случайно вставил в текст нерабочую версию кода. сейчас все исправил, в JS все работает. сообщение об ошибке в TS никуда не пропало.

Comment: код упрощен для простоты его прочтения.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно создать следующий тип:

```
interface Type<T, K> extends Function {
    (model: Model): K;
    new(...args: any[]): T;
}
```

И возвращать его из метода `FABRIC`.

В `T` необходимо передавать тип, который будет возвращаться при создании экземпляра через `new`.
Вместо `K`, нужно указать что будет возвращать вызов этого типа. В вашем случае это ваш метод `FABRIC`.

Comment: Что здесь делает `declare`?

Comment: Забыл убрать, в целом ничего страшного в его наличии все-равно не будет.